# Python Removing Non Latin Characters

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, unicode

How can I delete all the non latin characters from a string? More specifically, is there a way to find out Non Latin characters from unicode data?

Comment: `myString.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore')` or `errors='replace'`?

Comment: @Torxed: why would decoding UTF-8 give errors to ignore for non-Latin characters?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Using the third-party [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), you could remove all non-Latin characters with

```
import regex
result = regex.sub(ur'[^\p{Latin}]', u'', text)
```

If you don't want to use the regex module, [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) lists Latin unicode blocks:

```
\p{InBasic_Latin}: U+0000–U+007F
\p{InLatin-1_Supplement}: U+0080–U+00FF
\p{InLatin_Extended-A}: U+0100–U+017F
\p{InLatin_Extended-B}: U+0180–U+024F
\p{InLatin_Extended_Additional}: U+1E00–U+1EFF
```

So you could use these to form a character class using Python's builtin re module:

```
import re
result = re.sub(ur'[^\x00-\x7F\x80-\xFF\u0100-\u017F\u0180-\u024F\u1E00-\u1EFF]', u'', text)
```

---

Demo:

```
In [24]: import re
In [25]: import regex

In [35]: text = u'aweerwq\u0645\u0631\u062d\u0628\u0627\u043c\u0438\u0440'

In [36]: print(text)
aweerwqمرحباмир

In [37]: regex.sub(ur'[^\p{Latin}]', u'', text)
Out[37]: u'aweerwq'

In [38]: re.sub(ur'[^\x00-\x7F\x80-\xFF\u0100-\u017F\u0180-\u024F\u1E00-\u1EFF]', u'', text)    
Out[38]: u'aweerwq'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But when I tried using the method on text = "aweerwq", it gave me the result as "a". However, what I need is that non latin characters (like Arabic or maybe Russian characters) must be deleted and the normal alphabets/numbers should be retained.

Comment: sadly the `\p{Latin}` doesn't include punctuations and spaces =(

Comment: @alvas: You could use [`\p{posix_punct}`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) to match punctuation. It can be combined with `\p{Latin}` e.g. `regex.match(r'[\p{Latin}\p{posix_punct}]', 'abc?')`.

Comment: Correction: `regex.match(r'[\p{Latin}\p{posix_punct}]+', 'abc?')` -- I was missing a plus sign.

Comment: I liked your answer using python regex module so I translated it to Python 3:
re.sub(u'[^\\x00-\\x7F\\x80-\\xFF\\u0100-\\u017F\\u0180-\\u024F\\u1E00-\\u1EFF]', u'', text)

Answer (score 4):

In order to remove the non latin characters from a string, You can use the following regex to remove all the non-ascii characters from the string :

```
import re
result = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]',r'', text)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem (Python 3). You could try something like this.

```
text = u'aweerwq\u0645\u0631\u062d\u0628\u0627\u043c\u0438\u0440'
stripped_text = ''
for c in text:
   stripped_text += c if len(c.encode(encoding='utf_8'))==1 else ''
print(stripped_text)
aweerwq
```

Comment: This will also strip non-ASCII Latin characters (such as those with diacritical marks) which the OP probably does not want.